# Formpanel not visible in tabview

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, tabpanel

Here my code in sencha for my applicaiton,I have included table and two buttons in  resetpanel and addded into tab view

```
var tab= Ext.create('Ext.List', {
                       fullscreen: true,
                       dock: 'left',
                       width: 320,
                       height: 200,
                       ui: 'round',
                       store: {
                       fields: ['ext_xtype'],
                       data: [{
                              ext_xtype: 'fieldset',
                              }, {
                              ext_xtype: 'formpanel',
                              }]
                       }, 
                       itemTpl: '<span style="width:300px; display:inline-block;">{ext_xtype}</span> '
                       });
var resetPanel1  = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
                   id: 'resetPanel1',
                   style:{background:'#D8D8D8'},
                   dockedItems:[]
                   ,
                   items: [tab,{
                   xtype:  'button',
                   text:   'Add',
                   ui: 'confirm',
                   handler: function() {
                               view.setActiveItem('welcomepanel', {type:'fade', direction:'left'});
                                       }
                  },{
                   xtype:  'button',
                   text:   'Add',
                   ui: 'Search',
                  handler: function() {
                         view.setActiveItem('welcomepanel', {type:'fade', direction:'left'});
                                      }}]});
 var view = Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
                                  fullscreen: true,
                                  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
                                  scroll:'vertical',
                                  items: [{
                                          title: 'ITEMS',
                                          iconCls: 'star',
                                          layout:'card',
                                          items: [{
                                                  docked: 'top',
                                                  xtype: 'titlebar',
                                                  title: 'Add Items',
                                                  },resetPanel1
                                                  ]
                                          }]
                                  });
            Ext.Viewport.add(view);
 }
 });
```

The resetPanel1 is not viewing in tab view.Whats wrong with my code.Please help me to sort it out.

Comment: let me know my answer helped or not

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `fullscreen` and `dock` properties from the list, you should have `fullscreen : true` only in the main view, In your case `TabPanel`.

```
var tab= Ext.create('Ext.List', {
     width: 320,
     height: 200,
     ui: 'round',
    store: {
      fields: ['ext_xtype'],
      data: [{
         ext_xtype: 'fieldset',
        },{
         ext_xtype: 'formpanel',
        }]
   }, 
  itemTpl: '<span style="width:300px; display:inline-block;">{ext_xtype}</span>'
});
```